# React Router redirect to another component after refreshing or entering URL manually

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I open a modal after clicking a row in a table. When user clicks the row that is also reflected in the URL. But when user refreshes the page when the modal is open, user should be redirect to another component that shows modal content in fullpage.

```
<Route path="/payments-list" element={<Payments searchParams={searchParams} navigate={navigate} />} />
<Route path="/payments-list/:id" element={<Payments searchParams={searchParams} navigate={navigate} />} />
<Route path="/payments-list/:id" element={<PaymentWrapper />} />

const PaymentWrapper = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  return <PaymentDetail paymentId={id} fullPage={true} onClose={() => console.log} />;
};
```

these are the routes. Basically if users clicks a row in <Payments component it will open the payment detail modal. But if the user refreshes the pages, should be redirected to PaymentWrapper component.
In short I want to implement post display logic in Reddit.

Comment: It can be done using history state. Can you edit your example though to include the links/navigate calls on row click? It will be easier for me to describe the solution.

Comment: You can't have two `path="/payments-list/:id"` routes within the same `Routes` components. Can you [edit] to more clearly explain the use case and what the issue is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this is by way of history state. The link that the user follows needs to inject some history state which indicates they came from within the app. The good thing about the history state for this scenario is it will not be there if they come from the outside. Refresh is a bit more complicated, but we will come to that.

Firstly you can only have one component on the same route, so you need to have only one `<Route>` for the URL, but you will then be able to branch based on if they came from the app or from the outside within that single route. For the sake of example, I am going to use `PaymentsWrapper`. So remove the first `/payments-list/:id` route and keep the second one:

```
<Route path="/payments-list/:id" element={<PaymentWrapper />} />
```

Now, wherever you navigate to this URL (from your code it looks like you are using `navigate()` calls), change it to put a flag in the history state. `fromApp` isn't special, it's just something we made up to indicate that they came from inside the app. `state` can contain anything.

```
navigate('/payments-list/1234', {state: { fromApp: true }}})
```

If you use `<Link>` instead you can do it via the [`state` prop](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/link#state).

Now inside `PaymentWrapper` you can do whatever you need by using the flag:

```
const PaymentWrapper = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const { state: { fromApp } } = useLocation();

  if (fromApp) {
    return // Whatever you need here for what is shown when navigating from inside the app
  }

  return // Whatever you need here for what is shown when refreshing or navigating from the outside
};
```

So what about refreshing? The push state persists on refresh, so if you need to have this switch modes on refresh, you can add an effect in a high-up component like `<App>` -- somewhere above your router.

```
const navigate = useNavigate()
useEffect(() => {
   navigate(window.location.pathname, {replace: true, state: { fromApp: false }})      
}, [])
```

Since the only way to trigger this effect would be on a hard refresh (as long as it's high up in your app), it will clear down the flag. `replace` here ensures that an extra history item isn't added on each refresh.

Comment: Thank you, this worked well. I only replaced window.location.href with window.location.pathname